# What is difference between developer portal vs deprecated developer portal on Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm confusing to use the developer portal or deprecated developer portal on Azure API Management. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

There's a former developer portal that was replaced by a newer one.
This page contains images of the former developer portal:
[Getting started with Azure API Management](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip197.html)

[image]

The new developer portal has a modern look and feel:

[Overview of the developer portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal)
[image]

> **Important**
> The legacy developer portal is now deprecated and it will receive security updates only. You can continue to use it, as per usual, until its retirement in October 2023, when it will be removed from all API Management services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-deprecated-migration